# Keyframes/poses are not being interpolated armature/mesh

Tags: animation, pose-mode, timeline, dopesheet

I created poses and then apllied different mouth poses on different keyframes but it is not working.
Let's say i want my object to say "HAPY"
At keyframe 0 applied pose "BMP" for closed mouth
[image]
At keyframe 5 applied pose "H"
[image]
At keyframe 10 applied pose "A"
[image]
At keyframe 15 applied pose  "P"
[image]
At keyframe 20 applied pose  "Y"
[image]
At keyframe 25 applied pose  "BMP" for closed mouth
[image]

When i play animation it only plays from keyframe 20 to 25 and remains still.
I don't know what is causing this problem [Here is my File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13DJRS6m78h3l_vG3Qxj9S-xGZNwTpiRq/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable the *Animation: Pose Library* addon, then in the 3D view, press on the *N panel > Animation* tab, choose the pose you want. As you've enabled the *Auto Keying* option in the *Timeline*, it will do it automatically insert keyframes.

[image]

Comment: It is weird that single click adds a keyframe from animation tab but does not interpolate between them but a double click does solve the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, it works fine for me